# Python/Kivy KeyError

Tags: python, kivy, keyerror

I faced this problem: KeyError: 'city'. I get data from my database and put this data in dictionary.
My code:
Main.py

```
for row in rows:
    city_dict = {'city': row[2]}
    C = ClinicBanner(city=city_dict['city'])
    result_banner.add_widget(C)
```

Clinicbanner.py

```
class ClinicBanner(GridLayout):
    rows = 1
    def __init__(self, city, **kwargs):
        super(ClinicBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        centre = FloatLayout()
        centre_button = Button(text=kwargs['city'], size_hint=(1, .8), pos_hint={"top": .2, "left": 1})
        centre.add_widget(centre_button)

        self.add_widget(centre)
```

And I got this error: 
line 14, in **init**
centre_button = Button(text=kwargs['city'], size_hint=(1, .8), pos_hint={"top": .2, "left": 1}) 
KeyError: 'city'

I really hope that you can help me.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting TypeError: object.\_\_init\_\_() takes no parameters Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684725/getting-typeerror-object-init-takes-no-parameters-kivy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the city argument in the **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, city, **kwargs):
```

Why do not use it:

```
centre_button = Button(text=city, size_hint=(1, .8), pos_hint={"top": .2, "left": 1})
```